# Treat `null` as `undefined` in Joi validation

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

Optional variable is validated and conditioned with Joi:

```
optional = Joi.attempt(optional, Joi.array().optional().default([]));
```

Replacing `undefined` with `null` is common and convenient for optional params, it should treat `null` as `undefined` and fall back to default value.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: So the problem is that if you pass `null`, it won't fall back to `[]`, but instead it will set `null` as the value?

Comment: @JoshBeam Yes. And I really hope that there may be less ugly way of using Joi than `Joi.attempt(optional === null ? undefined : optional, ...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also was struggling with it for some time, but today finally found a solution. You have to use `empty(null)` to achieve the desired effect:

```
import * as joi from "joi";

const testSchema = joi.array().items(joi.string()).empty(null).allow(null).default([]);

const data1 = undefined;
const data2 = null;
const data3 = [];

const res1 = joi.validate(data1, testSchema);
const res2 = joi.validate(data2, testSchema);
const res3 = joi.validate(data3, testSchema);


console.log("res1", res1.value, res1.error);
console.log("res2", res2.value, res2.error);
console.log("res3", res3.value, res2.error);
```

Returns:

```
res1 [] null
res2 [] null // <-- victory
res3 [] null
```

Comment: ouch, someone got it all worked out already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44404799/npm-joi-with-null-undefined-empty-values-and-a-default-value

Comment: Great, this solves the problem. Thanks for the reference to related question

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar experience with Joi and the answer is that Joi's area of concern is **validation**. It shouldn't be responsible for *changing* the data that it receives (although, they have built such functionality in such as `string.replace` which does break this principal).

If you are expecting `null` or `Array` items, you will need to build Joi functionality to validate that you have in fact received a `null` or `Array`  item, and then implement your own logic on the received data knowing that it will be in the form that you have defined.